# Using Floating Action Button With Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, floating-action-button

I am using floating action button with slidingtablayout, but when i use fab in fragments every tab will have its own fab, and transition looks bad like this video from google design 
http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsNVRkV3FZMktvMWc/components-buttons-fab-behavior_06_xhdpi_009.webm
When i use fab in the viewpager it shrinks fragments like in the link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6vpKpg_w4tcEJQUUlRazd0VEk/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.smooth.www.smooth.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and one of my tabs

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:id="@+id/main_fab"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:transitionName="@string/fab_transition_name"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_image"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main_recycler"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

what can i do to for transitions to look good??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different implementation for a floating action button in each fragment of an activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163379/different-implementation-for-a-floating-action-button-in-each-fragment-of-an-act)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ar using a LinearLayout or something, instead of RelativeLayout. Can you post code snippets?

Comment: I added one of my tabs and main_activity

Comment: A quick look doesn't show me any major problems, but i do have a question. Why is that layout_weight there in the main layout?