# Is it possible to set different actions for floating action button in differet fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

I am working or an app where I have 4 fragments in viewpager and floating action button (fab). When I click on fab there appear 3 subfabs. Each of them start different activities where user can search data from different fragments. Is it possible to set fab so that if I click on it while I'm in first fragment it'll open an activity for searching inside this fragment, onClick inside second - search for second and etc. The issue is that now clicking on sub fab while I'm in some fragment I can search data from another fragment too and it's a bit weird. I understand question is kinda strange, if something is unclear I'll explain further

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make FAB button public and implement onClick listener in each fragment.
You should override **setUserVisibleHint** and put your code **onResume**  so getActivity() will not return null. Fab button will have different actions in different fragments.

Here's an example, inside each fragment when you want Fab click listener:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed())
    {            
        onResume();
    }
}

 @Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
    {
        return;
    }

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
    mainActivity.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //Do what you want
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check in onclick method of floating action button which fragment is currently opened and calling it.

Call `findFragmentById()` on `FragmentManager` and determine which fragment is in your `R.id.frameTitle` container.